# What is the interpretation of coefficients in path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

Say we want the amplitude for particles starting at x,y with distribution f(x,y) and ending up at w,z with distribution w,z.

Given a functionals:

$F[\phi] = \int f(x,y)\phi(x,t)\phi(y,t) dx^3 dy^3$

$G[\phi] = \int g(w,z)\phi(w,t')\phi(z,t') dw^3 dz^3$

and a path integral:

$$ \int F[\phi]G[\phi]e^{i S[\phi]} D\phi $$

How would you describe the distributions f(x,y) and g(w,z)? I know they must be symmetric functions for bosons and antisymmetric for fermions so can they be called distributions?

For example is f:

"The amplitude for finding particles at both x and y?"

"The correlation between finding particles at x and y?"

"The amplitude for particles being created/destroyed at x and y?"

Also if $\left<\phi|0\right>$ is the ground state equal to $\int^{\Phi_0=\phi} e^{iS[\Phi]}D\Phi$ then what is $<\phi|a^+(p)|0>$ in terms of path integrals? This is related to the first question in that the first question is related to $<0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0>$.

I know that the quantum mechanical amplitude for finding a particle at x is $\psi(x)$ and that $|\psi> = \int \psi(x)e^{i x.p} a^+(p) dp^4 dx^4 |0>$ from this  here bottom of page 43: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf

Comment: Nitpicks and remarks: 1. The usual notation for a $n$-dimensional integral measure is $\mathrm{d}^n x$, not $\mathrm{d}x^n$. 2. $\int F[\phi]G[\phi] \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}S[\phi]} \mathcal{D}\phi$ is **not** the amplitude for getting from $F$ to $G$ (whatever that means, since it is not clear whether $F$ and $G$ are even admissible wavefunctionals. Generally, one should avoid working with wavefunctionals), it's the *expectation value* for the operator $F[\phi]G[\phi]$. 3. You can't talk about particles if you don't have a free field.

Comment: Because of the above, it's *unclear what you're asking*. You need to be more careful about what exactly the objects you are writing down are and what exactly they signify. In particular, one cannot switch so freely between the wavefunctional formalism and the path integral formalism as you seem to desire.

Comment: Here is a paper giving the link between path integrals and states showing that it perfectly possible to switch freely between them: http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/4-pathintegrals.pdf